# objects classes and arrays - why is it returning 'null' ? [java]

Tags: java, arrays, class, object

I wrote a small class that creates a report object containing 3 arrays. At creation of the object these arrays are initialised with values. However when i test the class to see for example what's in the departments array, it prints out that the array elements are null. why?

```
 class  Report
 {
        // declare instance variables (arrays)
        public String[] departments = new String[4] ;
        public double[] grossTotals = new double[4] ;
        public double[] taxTotals = new double[4]  ;


        // constructor
        public Report(){
            // declare, create and initialise all in one statement
            String[] departments = {"Accounting", "Sales", "HR", +
                                              "Administration"} ;
            double[] grossTotals = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0} ;
            double[] taxTotals = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0} ;

    } // END constructor
 } // class  Report
```

Test Class:

```
 class TestReport 
 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // create report object
            Report r = new Report();

                for (int i = 0; i <= 3 ; i++ )
                {
                System.out.println(r.departments[i]) ;
                }

        } //end main
 } // end test class
```

thanks

Baba

Comment: By the way, publicizing arrays (as in public String[]) is a bad habit. Other code can now change those arrays. Even `public final` doesn't fix that, as the contents can still be changed. With arrays it's best to make them private (and possibly `static final` as well) where possible.

Comment: HI, thanks that is correct. However then i would need a getter method to retrieve the data from the test class which my example does not have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it like this

```
public Report(){
            // declare, create and initialise all in one statement
            this.departments = {"Accounting", "Sales", "HR", +
                                              "Administration"} ;
            this.grossTotals = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0} ;
            this.taxTotals = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0} ;

    } // END constru
```

Actually you are creating new arrays objects local to your constructor those are getting initialized in constructor.

your class fields will be initialized using the code above .

[If you have not done it by mistake than please refer to this doc also it will better clear your understandings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

**

### Update

:**
Above code will give you illegal start of expression

Here is working code

```
 class  Report
 {
        // declare instance variables (arrays)
        public String[] departments = null;
        public double[] grossTotals = null;
        public double[] taxTotals = null;


        // constructor
        public Report(){
              this.departments = new String[]{"Accounting", "Sales", "HR", "Administration"} ;
         this.grossTotals = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0} ;
         this.taxTotals = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0} ;
    } // END constructor
 }
```

Comment: Perhaps nice to add that the problem he's having is called 'field shadowing'. That is, you create local variables with the same name as member/instance variables.

Comment: thanks very much for your help! i tested and it seems that your solution can be further simplified by removing "=null". seems it's not needed. thanks again!

Comment: @Baba thats true null is optional there

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have noted, your constructor created new local variables "shadowing" the instance variables instead of populating the instance variables with data.

However, the population code is a little different if you separate the declaration from the populating, and they didn't get that quite right.  You also had a '+' character that didn't belong.

This code compiles and works (tested), and does basically what your looking for.

```
class  Report
{
       // declare instance variables (arrays)
       public String[] departments;
       public double[] grossTotals;
       public double[] taxTotals;


       // constructor
       public Report(){
           // populate instance variables
           departments = new String[]{"Accounting", "Sales", "HR",
                                             "Administration"} ;
           grossTotals = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0} ;
           taxTotals = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0} ;

   } // END constructor
} // class  Report
```

You can alternatively create the arrays in the declaration and then populate the array entries in the constructor or elsewhere.

With that approach the code could be something like:

```
class  Report
{
       // declare instance variables (arrays)
       public String[] departments = new String[4];
       public double[] grossTotals = new double[4];
       public double[] taxTotals = new double[4];


       // constructor
       public Report(){
           // populate instance variable entries
           departments[0] = "Accounting";
           departments[1] = "Sales";
           departments[2] = "HR";
           departments[3] = "Administration";

           for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
               grossTotals[i] = 0.0;
               taxTotals[i] = 0.0;

           }
   } // END constructor
} // class  Report
```

As a third alternative, you can do all the initialization in the field declaration as follows:

```
class  Report
{
       // declare and populate instance variables (arrays)
       public String[] departments = new String[]{"Accounting", "Sales", "HR",
                                             "Administration"} ;
       public double[] grossTotals = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0} ;
       public double[] taxTotals = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0} ;

} // class  Report
```

In this case, you don't need to define the constructor at all, as it does nothing.  An empty one will be supplied by Java.

Comment: Thanks Don! I did understand what the others were pointing out but their solution didn't work. So, the solution is to populate the array elements individually. It is surprising though because syntactically i couldn't see anything wrong with a one-line statement popuating the array. Thanks again! Baba (re +: that was just a layout thing for this post but i see i didn't need it)