# Null Pointer Exception with a 2d array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, 2d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [objects classes and arrays - why is it returning ‘null’ ? [java]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178358/objects-classes-and-arrays-why-is-it-returning-null-java)

The other questions with similar titles all have the answer that their data needs to be initialized which I have done but I'm still getting a null pointer exception. Could anyone tell me why?

```
    public class grid{
private Node [][] board = new Node [9][9];

public boolean add(int x, int y, char label) {
    boolean valid=true;

    System.out.println("enter add");
    if(label==' '){
        System.out.println("enter if 1");
        board[x][y].setValue('0');
    }
    else if(label<='9'&&label>'0'){
        System.out.println("enter if 2");
        board[x][y].setValue(label);
    }
    else{
        valid=false;
    }
    if(valid)
        System.out.println("valid");
    return valid;
}
```

I'm getting the error on the setValue Lines (10 and 14)

```
    public class Node{
public char value;
public char []  possibleValues = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
public boolean correct=false;
    }
```

Edit: I figured it out, if anyone else has the same problem, this seems to fix it.

```
    if(label==' '){
        System.out.println("enter if 1");
        board[x][y]= new Node(' ');
    }
    else if(label<='9'&&label>'0'){
        System.out.println("enter if 2");
        board[x][y]= new Node(label);
    }
```

Comment: Your char array should be `public char []  possibleValues = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};` Your code might not even complie.

Comment: @smit - It will compile just fine, it just won't do what he thinks. A `char` in java is simply a 16bit signed integer. Using single quotes gets the value for a given character from the default character map. (e.g. '1' == 49 if you're using UTF-8 )

Comment: @BrianRoach +1  Yes you are right..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array does not initialize the elements of the array. So, each `board[x][y]` will be initially `null`.

Comment: Oh, what is this doing then?

private Node [][] board = new Node [9][9];

Comment: @Iweir - Not what you think. See the duplicate of this question I linked to, or the tutorial on arrays http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Okay, the thing is for this I'll be using directing input so I don't know the values until a file is given. I'm a bit confused on how I would initialize it then.

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out and I'll update the OP